# How two secure elements can safely authenticate each other without a third party?

Tags: authentication, man-in-the-middle

Assume there are multiple secure elements, and also multiple man-in-the-middle or malwares. How can any two secure elements authenticate each other without a third party and hard coding something in all elements? Since a hard coded code is vulnerable and can be attacked by brute force.